# IOS Stop reading data from Firebase immediately after tapping a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase

XCode Version: 5.1.1

Currently I have the following codes to read data from Firebase

```
FirebaseHandle h = [firebaseRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    //do something...
}
[self addFirebaseHandleForRemoval:h forRef:firebaseRef];
```

Because heavy(big in size) stuff (images, audios) are stored in firebase, therefore, it takes quite a long time (a few minutes) to read and load those assets from firebase.
I desire to have a UIButton. And when I tap that button, it will stop reading and loading data (images, audios) from Firebase immediately.

In addtion, I also want to resume loading stuff after I tap that button again.

Comment: IMHO it is extremely inefficient to use firebase as file storage, especially for "heavy stuff" you mentioned. have a look at Firebase.goOnline() / goOffline()

Comment: Firebase.goOnline()/goOffline(), what are these methods called in Objective-C?